# kubernetes does not evict pods while exceeding ephemeral storage in case of containers with desktop environment

Tags: kubernetes

I have deployed this image in k8s (1.28) and set a limit for ephemeral storage.

https://github.com/danielguerra69/ubuntu-xrdp/tree/master

This image provides an ubuntu desktop environment accessible using RDP. I have problem in limiting the ephemeral storage in practice.

When i add a file at /tmp larger than the limit using kubectl exec -it pod -- /bin/bash, the pod gets evicted. but when i access the pod using the rdp (via node port service) and make a large file at the same directory the eviction does not happen. what is the problem? how to apply ephemeral storage limit in this case?

this is my yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubuntu-desktop-pod2
  labels:
    app: ubuntu-desktop-pod2
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ubuntu-desktop2
    image: danielguerra/ubuntu-xrdp:20.04
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    ports:
      - containerPort: 3389
      - containerPort: 22
    volumeMounts:
      - name: shm-volume
        mountPath: /dev/shm
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 5 # Replace with your desired CPU limit
        memory: 9Gi # Replace with your desired memory limit
        ephemeral-storage: "20Gi"
      limits:
        cpu: 6 # Replace with your desired CPU limit
        memory: 10Gi # Replace with your desired memory limit
        ephemeral-storage: "21Gi"
  volumes:
    - name: shm-volume
      emptyDir:
        medium: Memory
        sizeLimit: 256Mi
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ubuntu-desktop-service2
spec:
  selector:
    app: ubuntu-desktop-pod2
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: rdp 
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3389
    - name: ssh 
      protocol: TCP
      port: 22
```